# Regex pattern doesnt work

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an issue with `Validators.pattern` with a following regex:

```
/^[_a-z0-9]+([_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+([a-z0-9-]+)*([a-z]{2,4})$/
```

which should verify email address. You can check out the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YNtG65JGnGYSLVzcgMTO?p=preview). If you delete `Validators.pattern(..)`, the form will work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `pattern` wasn't yet avaliable in beta.37 which you're using in your Plunker.

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: angular2_1.Validators.pattern is not a function

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uUY4hU?p=preview)

Comment: Good eyes! However, in my project I use the newest beta, and still have the same issue. I will update the plnkr in a few

Comment: I added a link to a Plunker. I changed a few things. I think you need to use ` (backtick) instead of `"` and no `/` around the regexp.

Comment: this theoretically works, but it will always give a form "INVALID" like here https://plnkr.co/edit/W7wiBKgkIKecS2wpXaQ1?p=preview

Comment: I'mm not using TypeScript or JS myself (only Dart). Maybe the ` isn't the right way to wrap the regex. I just checked it doesn't produce an error and the form value is shown.

Comment: ` seems to be fine. `"` requires `$` to be escaped as `\$`. The problem is probably the email regex. It works fine with simpler regex or when the the email doesn't contain a `.` like `abc@def` but `abc@def.com` is shown as invalid.

Comment: There is still an open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7595
This prevents `pattern` being bound to. The pattern needs to be statically added to the DOM (without binding) to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the built-in email validation:

```
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" type="email">
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Comment: in angular2 `ng-model` should be `[(ngModel)]`